# Discord.js fetch user with id

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Good evening, I just want to fetch a user with the id, but when I replace the id with a variable it doesn't work anymore. Does anyone have any idea?

working:

```
client.users.fetch("765574410119282749").then(async (user) => {console.log(user)})
```

not working:

```
var id = "765574410119282749"
client.users.fetch(id).then(async (user) => {console.log(user)})
```

i use discord.js V13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code working you need to use `client.users.cache.get("id")`, so your code will look like this:

```js
var id = "765574410119282749"
let user = client.users.cache.get(id); 
console.log(user)
```